# Why is it necessary to escape the bar Ex-command separator in mapping definitions but not in command line in Vim?

Tags: vim, command-line, escaping

I don’t understand why the following commands do different things.

Pasted in the `.vimrc` file, both of the commands define two versions of a mapping triggered by pressing `t` in Normal mode:

```
nnoremap t :call search('\m\(a\|b\)', 'W')<CR>
nnoremap t :call search('\m\(a\\|b\)', 'W')<CR>
```

Compare the effects of the above mappings with the results of running those search calls directly from the command line:

```
:call search('\m\(a\|b\)', 'W')
:call search('\m\(a\\|b\)', 'W')
```

To be specific, the “intended” behavior requires `\\|` in the `nnoremap` example, but it requires `\|` in the `call` search example.

I’m aware that the special treatment of the vertical bar character (`:help :bar`) is one of those traps that Vim has laid out for me, but it still doesn’t make sense. The documentation clearly says that “*this list of commands will see bar as part of their argument*”, but none of those exceptions apply here.

All the commands involved in this example treat bar as a meta concatenate character. Moreover, in this situation, the bar is inside a string, and—I think?—being parsed as part of a string takes priority over meta concatenate syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indeed, the issue is caused by the special treatment of the bar
character by the mapping-creating commands.

The key-mapping mechanism in Vim is a way of making a sequence of key
presses to be interpreted as another sequence of keys; no semantic
interpretation of Vimscript language happens at this level. Since, in
order to create a mapping, it is necessary to separate both of the
key-sequence arguments to be mapped, commands of the `:map`-family
start by determining the boundaries of the two arguments. To make use
of characters that could interfere with this process in a mapping, one
must use escaping syntax provided for those characters (among which
are the carriage return, space, backslash, and bar characters).

Because the bar character can be used to separate a mapping command
from the next Ex command and, therefore, to define the ending boundary
of the right-hand-side of the mapping, it cannot be used as-is in
a key sequence. According to `:help map_bar`, depending on settings,
the bar character can be escaped as `<bar>`, `\|`, or `^V|` (where
`^V` denotes the literal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> key code).

Keeping that in mind, let us follow the mappings in question (around
the `\|`/`\\|` part) the way they are interpreted in the default
configuration. In the first mapping, the `\|` sequence is treated as
a single `|` character. Therefore, after that mapping command is
executed, pressing `t` will be the same as typing

`:call search('\m\(a|b\)', 'W')`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

When the second mapping command is run, the `\\|` string is
interpreted as a literal backslash character (there is no need to
escape `\` in the right-hand-side of mappings, except for nested ones)
followed by the `\|` specifier representing a bar character.
Thus, this command maps `t` to the following:

`:call search('\m\(a\|b\)', 'W')`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

However, when one types the mapped search calls in Command-line mode,
unlike key sequences in mappings, they are interpreted as Ex commands
right away. Those bar characters occur in string literals, so there is
no possibility of misinterpreting them as separators for Ex commands.
When directly typed in, the commands are sent to execution as they are
written. Thus, the difference between them are due to the meaning of
the regular expressions `\m\(a\|b\)` and `\m\(a\\|b\)`, not due to
any kind of escaping behavior.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up.  I certainly overlooked how `:map` commands have to parse their arguments without semantically looking at their content.

Answer (score 7):

When you use vim's `*map` and `command` commands, the vimscript engine doesn't interpret the command - it stores it as is, as a keystroke sequence(in case of `*map`) or as a string(in case of `command`). The command is only interpreted when you use it.

Because of that, when you map the command, vim doesn't really know your pipe character is inside a string, because he doesn't know or care if there are strings in your command, at least not in that stage.

If you want to use `|` in a `*map`, you need to use `<bar>` instead.