# Vim foldexpr matching pattern1 OR pattern2?

Tags: vim

I want vim to create folds for my markdown files based on the header lines such
that for all lines below a particular header will be folded. E.g:

```
# Header
some lines of
text here

## Sub-header
some more lines of
text here # and a comment for some reason
    # and an indented comment for good measure

# Another header
A new set of lines with a blank line(!)

for this header

## Another sub-header
yet more text
```

Should be folded like so:

```
# Header
+-- 2 lines: - some lines of -------------------

## Sub-header
+-- 3 lines: - some more lines of --------------

# Another header
+-- 3 lines: - A new set of lines --------------

## Another sub-header
yet more text
```

(I don't know what happens for a fold on a single line, so I'm happy with
whatever vim's default is - i.e. if vim doesn't do folds for single lines,
that's fine by me)

I've tried coming up with different regular expressions for this... I can match
all non-header lines **except** for blank lines:

```
autocmd FileType markdown setlocal foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~'^[^#]'
```

So I tried adding a second pattern to capture
blank lines with variation of `^[^#]\|^\s*$` (which does match everything but
non-header lines when I use it in a simple search with `/`) but then no folds
are produced and I don't know why (I tried different amounts of escape slashes
but to no avail):

```
" none of these work
autocmd FileType markdown setlocal foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~'^[^#]\|^\s*$'
autocmd FileType markdown setlocal foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~'^[^#]\\|^\\s*$'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there...you need 3 backslashes:

```
foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~'^[^#]\\\|^\\s*$'
```

Your regex string needs to end up having both a backslash and a vertical bar. Both of these characters need to be escaped in the expression. So you end up with `\\` and `\|`...or 3 backslashes total.

[source / additional reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695168/why-is-it-necessary-to-escape-the-bar-ex-command-separator-in-mapping-definition)

(side note: you could also switch to "very magic" mode with `\\v`, which would result in `'\\v^[^#]\|^\\s*$'`. If you had multiple "very magic" characters (e.g. `|(){}+`) this would be super helpful...but with a single vertical bar the only thing it might do is help with readability.)